# What is the proper way to duplicate componentDidMount with hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble understanding the proper way to recreate the behavior of the `componentDidMount` life cycle function using react hooks.

I have found the generally accepted method is like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //do componentDidMount stuff here
}, []);
```

However, when theres additional parameters, other dependencies, etc. I get linting errors, as in this example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(design, onSuccess, onError);
}, []);
```

That one throws linting errors. What would be the proper way to handle that type of scenario? I'd like to avoid disabling eslint.

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'design' and 'onSuccess'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: What type of error does it throws ? The form is correct

Comment: Just change `[]` to `[activeImage]`. You can take a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Comment: @Vencovsky updated it to a better example

Comment: Show the lint error, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880). I found it very interesting.

You can also take a look at [Two Ways to Be Honest About Dependencies](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#two-ways-to-be-honest-about-dependencies) that Aron mentions on his answer. It's very interesting and goot to understand hooks dependencies.

---

> I'd like to avoid disabling eslint.

So to do that, here is what you need to do.

In the issue, some one gives an [example](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485936545) where he calls a function from outside of the `useEffect`.

```
const hideSelf = () => {
    // In our case, this simply dispatches a Redux action
};


// Automatically hide the notification
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        hideSelf();
    }, 15000);
}, []);
```

And by reading all the comments and looking at [Dan Abramov comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-486638525)

> ... But in this specific example the idiomatic solution is to put `hideSelf` inside the effect

So this means doing

```
// Automatically hide the notification
useEffect(() => {
    const hideSelf = () => {
        // In our case, this simply dispatches a Redux action
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
        hideSelf();
    }, 15000);
}, []);
```

This an example where you can solve the problem without using disableling eslint.

If this isn't your case (maybe you use Redux or something alike) you should put it as a deppendency of the effect

> ... If it dispatches a Redux action then put this action as a dependency

To solve this problem, it deppends alot of your situation. You didn't give us a clear example of what is your case, so I found one an give you a generic solution.

## Short answer

Add everything that is outside of the effect in the effect dependency (inside `[]`)

OR

Declare the functions that are outside of the effect inside of it.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting these answers, can you explain?

Comment: @Ted the downvote doesn't matter that much, what matter is, did some of the asnwers solve your problem?

Comment: Both answers provided great information, and I upvoted both, but the downvotes zeroed that out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're getting the [`exhaustive-deps`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) error?

When using a `useEffect` the recommendation is to put all values that are used in the effect in the dependencies array, so that you are being "honest" about which values the effect uses. Dan Abramov talks about this here https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#two-ways-to-be-honest-about-dependencies.

However if you are happy to ignore this and are sure that you only want this effect to run the first time this component renders then you can safely ignore the lint errors using `// eslint-disable-line exhaustive-deps`.

**EDIT**: There isn't really a way round this because ultimately you are *not* being "honest" about your deps, strictly speaking.

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer: why? Is it incorrect?

Comment: Whoever is downvoting these answers, can you explain?

Comment: I upvoted this, because that linked article is great. The downvote zeroed that out, unfortunately.